# How to enable the new right-corner username menu in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome-os, multiple-users

I see  that in Google Chrome in Windows the old user avatar icon was replaced with a name-menu in the right corner.

How to get that in Linux Chromium?

[image]   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chrome://flags/#enable-new-avatar-menu

Set to 'enabled' and restart.

---

There is also another feature available now, which was not before: setting that to 'disabled' will show the Google account user image instead of the avatar, or that image will become available among the avatar images.

(It's like a bug: going directly from 'default to 'disabled' will not work. You have to go from default to enabled, relaunch and then disable and relaunch.)